# How do i make a nested match in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var matches = pattern.match(/\((.+?)\)/g);
```

matched against:

```
[e[1]]
```

returns "[e[1]", i assume it is a problem with nesting, how do I fix this?

Comment: `[e[1]]` produces null. Do you mean `(e(1))`?

Comment: Are you only interested in `[` and `]` (or `(` / `)` ) delimiters, or a more generic solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only interested in how to match substrings inside fixed delimiters, you may use `XRegExp` [`XRegExp.matchRecursive`](http://xregexp.com/api/#matchRecursive):

> Returns an array of match strings between outermost left and right delimiters, or an array of objects with detailed match parts and position data. An error is thrown if delimiters are unbalanced within the data.

Since the delimiters are lost, but you know what they are you can later restore them in all the matches.

```js
var str = '[e[1]] [ [e[[2]34]]]';
document.body.innerHTML = XRegExp.matchRecursive(str, '\\[', ']', 'g').map(x => '[' + x + ']');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/2.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You know anything like this for php? (for future reference)

Comment: In PHP PCRE, it is much easier: [`\[(?>[^][]++|(?R))*]`](https://regex101.com/r/gL9uG9/1).

Comment: What is the problem? It matches everything correctly.

Comment: is there something i can do so it matches the brackets inside the brackets?

Comment: One last thing, sorry I suck at regex, but can you make it match parenthesis instead of brackets?

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I would be nowhere without you :P